# Using a domain that includes some part of other domain

Tags: blog, domains, web-hosting

I recently bought this domain: www.stumbleat.com to blog about various Science and Technology related topics. 
I realised that there’s a very famous website by the name: StumbleUpon (www.stumbleat.com) already on the web.

My question is, are there any consequences to having a domain/name for a website that has some part of an already existing website.

After doing some research, I found out that StumbleUpon is moving to Mix now. In which case it shouldn’t be a problem, right?

Comment: `1)` I must say I didn't understood the situation - you bought `www.stumbleat.com`, but why you say that StumbleUpon is also `www.stumbleat.com`? Mistake? `2)` I think it's a question more suitable for [webmasters.se]

Comment: That’s not what I meant. I know both the domains are different but I’m concerned if there can be consequences since a part of domain on both are similar, in this case (stumble).

Comment: Ohh so besides from a possible confusion by someone - no. That's the only consequence. That's what you meant?

Comment: Not an issue. You should be fine! Cheers!!

Comment: BTW- Welcome to Pro Webmaters! You can come here for most of your online needs especially for things search and search performance related. We have some real experts here!!

Answer (score 1):

Stumble is a trademark owned by StumbleUpon therefore if you plan to provide similar content, similar design or similar concept then you would be infringing on [their trademark](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4807:vuiqr5.2.4) and you would most likely receive a takedown notice to your domain registrar, even if you have `trademarkRandomWord.com`.

You are however allowed to use trademarks in domain names if you serve a completely different niche, for example... brand sells cars, you sell cats. In terms of Google or Bing rankings, it doesn't matter until you receive a takedown notice and then your rankings will plummet.

Comment: Do people sell cats online? How does shipping work? Is USPS standard shipping okay? (Humor) I rather suspect the OP is fine as long as he does not deliberately go after the same content space as well as look and feel. A single term is defensable if that is all that it is. Cheers!!

Comment: I'm trying to build a blog which will be entirely focussed on science and technology, and nowhere close to StumbleUpon in terms of look and feel. As of now, on their website, it says, "StumbleUpon is moving to Mix." Will it still be something to worry about, now that they are moving to a different domain?